# how to configure mysql with apache ignite ? and use read-through ,write through features

Tags: spring-boot, ignite

I'm trying to configure 3rd party persistance (mysql) in apache ignite .I'm new to ignite and I'm using spring boot,can someone help me with it?

Comment: When you mean persistence you mean persist the caches to mysql?

Comment: just want to implement read through and write through . and store the value in cache to my db and load from it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use [GridGain Web Console](https://console.gridgain.com) to generate 3rd party persistence configuration for you. It will connect to your DB via Agent and generate cache configurations.

Then, you can see [DZone cache store example](https://dzone.com/articles/apache-ignite-how-to-read-data-from-persistent-sto) using custom CacheStore.

Finally, you can use [example provided with Ignite](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/store/auto/CacheAutoStoreExample.java).

Comment: Please check up: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/web-console/latest/automatic-rdbms-integration

Comment: GridGain is limited and at the end is not free

Comment: @AntalAttila GridGain's Web Console is free to use and its generated configurations are also absolutely free to use with stock Apache Ignite.

Comment: I am running ignite node with my spring boot . Is it possible to connect web console with that node ?

Comment: @TJ32 Yes, you have to add ignite-rest dependency and then Web Agent will automatically connect to your cluster (you need to download Web Agent from Web Console and run it).